# JQuery how to show/hide html when user clicks a <span> tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to toggle (show/hide) an HTML table when a user clicks on a menu item (a span tag), then pass the data to ajax so I can GET/POST to a php file. The ultimate goal is to show a comparison table based on the items as they are clicked.

The problem is that my str variable always comes back with 'undefined', so I can't pass it to PHP. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help me understand.  Thanks.

```js
//var str = $("#flip").innerHTML;
//var str = $(".flip").innerHTML;
var str = $("#results > flip").innerHTML;
console.log(str);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {

    $.get("panel.php?id=" + str, function(response) {
      // Log the response to the console for testing
      console.log("Response: " + response);
      $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">

  <span class="flip">123</span><br>
  <span class="flip">456</span><br>
  <span class="flip">789</span>

</div>

<div class="panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is a test.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Typo: `> flip` should be `> .flip`.

Comment: And `.innerHTML` should be `.html()` -- you can't use DOM properties on jQuery object.

Comment: But you're getting the HTML of the first span, not the one the user clicked on. You need to use `$(this).html()` inside the click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text of the clicked span, you need to get it inside the handler function. Use `$(this)` to refer to the one that was clicked on.

It's also better to use an object to specify the query parameters, to ensure that the value is escaped properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    let str = $(this).text();
    $.get("panel.php", {id: str}, function(response) {
      // Log the response to the console for testing
      console.log("Response: " + response);
      $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">

  <span class="flip">123</span><br>
  <span class="flip">456</span><br>
  <span class="flip">789</span>

</div>

<div class="panel" style="display: none;">
  <p>This is a test.</p>

</div>
```